# Regular Expression Has Syntax Error in Javascript Only

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to use a regular expression in Javascript but I am getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier ?.
```

The weird thing is that this exact regular expression works on this [website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). But when executed in javascript it fails?

Paste this `^/courses(/[a-z0-9\-]+){2,3}(/|\.jsp)?(\?.*)?$` into the [website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) and see it works.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var res = "/courses/applied-finance-postgraduate-qualifications/graduate-certificate-in-corporate-finance-3/?stid=b951f"
.replace( new RegExp("^/courses(/[a-z0-9\-]+){2,3}(/|\.jsp)?(\?.*)?$"), "abc");
```

Answer (score 5):

> What am I doing wrong?

The regular expression you are creating is

```
^/courses(/[a-z0-9-]+){2,3}(/|.jsp)?(?.*)?$
                                    ^^^^^
```

Note the `(?` part, which is illegal (and hence the error).

`\` is the escape character in string literals **and** regular expression. The parser doesn't know that there is a regular expression in the string literal, the `\` is evaluated as part of the string literal, so `\?` becomes `?`. Simple test:

```
> "\?"
"?"
```

You have the same problem with `\.jsp`, which becomes `.jsp`. The `.` is not illegal at that position, but it will match every character instead of a `.`.

If you want to pass it along to the regular expression, you have to escape it:

```
"^/courses(/[a-z0-9\\-]+){2,3}(/|\\.jsp)?(\\?.*)?$"
                                 ^        ^
```

Or you simple you use an expression literal (which requires you do escape the `/` though):

```
.replace(/^\/courses(\/[a-z0-9-]+){2,3}(\/|\.jsp)?(\?.*)?$/, "abc");
```